# MySQL update query with PHP causing error callback with AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm very new to PHP and backend web development, so forgive me if I do or say anything too stupid.

I'm trying to upload in image with PHP, use jQuery and AJAX to call the PHP function, and then use MySQL to store the image path of the data. For some reason though, when I try to send the query to the MySQL database to tell it to update the image path, it creates an error and uses the error callback for AJAX. I've tested the query, and it only creates an error when used in this function. I've also found that it doesn't create an error if I use a query that doesn't involve an UPDATE. I'm completely lost as to why this is happening.

Relevant code

HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input id="pic" type="file" name="Picture" />
    <button id="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
        var file_data = $('#pic').prop('files')[0];
        var form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file',file_data);
        alert(form_data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload.php',
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            type: 'post',
            success: function(response){
                alert("Success"+response);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('Error');
            }
        });
```

PHP 'upload.php'

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "foo";
$password = "bar";
$dbname = "name";
//
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Connected successfully";
$sql = "UPDATE table SET var='test' WHERE id=1";
$conn->query($sql);
?>
```

Comment: It it only happens for updates maybe the username doesn't have permissions to update that table

Comment: I tried logging in with a root user, and it doesn't seem to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

call the java-script code, on submit button click event,

```
$('#upload').on('click', function() { 

//the above java-script code;

});
```

Comment: I know how to append click events, I just didn't include the part of the code where that is done because it is not relevant to the problem.